# FDT code assist: cannot select option

Tags: eclipse, fdt

I am making the step from Flex Builder to FDT. Now I have configured the content assist to trigger at ".:_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" - which works close to great. I get all the options presented to me. However when I try to select one by double clicking the item or hitting enter - the selectionbox disappears, without leaving the selected option. This is greatly frustrating. How can I fix this? did I forget to toggle a checkbox somewhere like "fill in assist on enter"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FDT doesn't insert the selected entry in the List when you select it with enter or double mouse click?
This works for me in the latest 3.5 beta on Mac.
What FDT version and OS are you using?

Michael Plank, FDT Team